# Salvando dados ao selecionar opção

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho uma Activity que tem uma lista. Nessa lista, os campo são quase todos `RadioButton`. Atualmente, quando o usuário salva os dados selecionados nessa lista, é feita uma leitura de todos os `RadioButton` pra saber qual está marcado. Se tiver, pega a resposta, se não tiver ler mesmo assim.

Esse procedimento eu tenho achado lento, e ha possibilidades de a quantidade de campos aumentar, pois essa Activity é dinâmica, podendo diminuir ou aumentar a quantidade de campo.

Pensei em algo que é a minha dúvida:
Seria correto ou tem algum problema em, quando o usuário selecionar o campo eu já salvar no banco o que ele escolheu? E se ele precisar mudar, vai no banco novamente e alterar esse registro?

Ou seja, na medida em que o cara for marcando, os dados já serão registrados no banco.

Valeu!

Comment: Sempre poste os códigos referentes para ajudar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teoricamente, essa poderia ser uma opção **viável** , mas pense deste jeito:

**E se o usuário clicar no RadioButton errado?** 
Ele irá armazenar sempre no banco de dados a opção que foi clicada, sendo ela a que o usuário desejou ou não. O ponto negativo é que irá estar constantemente a introduzir informação no seu banco de dados.

**Possível Solução:**
Quando o usuário seleciona um RadioButton, ele será confrontado com uma mensagem perguntando se é mesmo aquele RadioButton que ele deseja selecionar ou se deseja fazer alguma alteração. Deste modo você evita assim estar constantemente a introduzir informação no seu banco de dados e ter que proceder à sua eliminação.

Comment: Era justamente nisso que estava pensando. Só que como é um preenchimento de formulário, pode ser um problema sempre apresentar uma msg pra ele confirmar. Isso vai tornar o preenchimento do formulário mais lento e desestimulante.

Comment: Sendo então um preenchimento de formulário, no final do seu preenchimento você pode disponibilizar uma página para o usuário perguntando para ele se a informação introduzida se encontra correta ou se ele deseja então alterar alguma coisa, e só depois da confirmação enviar para o banco de dados

Comment: Entendi. Só que eu não quero pegar os dados dos Radios, pois fica lento. Eu já faço isso. Quando é no fim do formulário, tem um botão FINALIZAR. Quando o usuário clica nele, é feita uma leitura dos Radios que estão selecionados e só então é gravado no banco. Porém isso tem se tornado lento na medida que os formulários tem mais perguntas. Onde eu armazenaria os dados antes de salvar, pra não ter que pegar direto dos Radios?

Comment: Você só deveria fazer essa leitura dos Radios no final do formulário, logo depois que o usuário clique em "Finalizar", porque há medida que ele vai preenchido e você tá armazenando o que ele preenche, vai tornando o seu sistema mais lento, estando ou não a inserir diretamente no banco de dados, mesmo que esteja só apenas a armazenar. A verificação dos dados inseridos deve, na minha opinião, ser apenas feita no final, evitando assim ir armazenando informação à medida do preenchimento do formulário, tornando este mais lento no final

Comment: Entendi Fábio. Desde já quero agradecer sua atenção. Mas me tira uma dúvida: essa minha questão aqui, é porque eu pensei que, como está demorando um pouco para finalizar a Activity ao salvar, esse procedimento fosse arriscado perder o formulário. Como são muitos Radios, todos são lidos para saber qual está marcado. Mas dessa forma que você está me indicando, eu já o faço.

Comment: De qualquer modo você pode fazer a verificação / validação de todos esses Radios, após o usuário clicar no botão de Finalizar e imediatamente antes de correr o evento do botão. Se estiver tudo de acordo e se o usuário não desejar fazer nenhuma alteração ao que foi selecionado por ele, aí você grava no banco de dados e tudo bem. Sua activity pode estar demorando para finalizar porque você tá coletando Radio a Radio à medida que o usuário vai clicando. Se o usuário selecionar uma opção do Radio por engano, você vai estar restringindo a performance da sua Activity, ficando assim mais lenta.